# \ufeff is appearing while reading csv using unicodecsv module

Tags: python, csv, unicode, python-3.9

I have following code

```py
import unicodecsv
CSV_PARAMS = dict(delimiter=",", quotechar='"', lineterminator='\n')
unireader = unicodecsv.reader(open('sample.csv', 'rb'), **CSV_PARAMS)
for line in unireader:
    print(line)
```

and it prints

```
['\ufeff"003', 'word one"']
['003,word two']
['003,word three']
```

The CSV looks like this

```
"003,word one"
"003,word two"
"003,word three"
```

I am unable to figure out why the first row has `\ufeff` (which is i believe a file marker). Moreover, there is `"` at the beginning of first row.

The CSV file is comign from client so i can't dictate them how to save a file etc. Looking to fix my code so that it can handle encoding.

Note: I have already tried passing `encoding='utf8'` to `CSV_PARAMS` and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Why are you using `unicodecsv`?  It is a workaround for Python 2 limitations, but the `csv` module in Python 3 overcomes that.

Comment: The issue exist for `csv` module too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`encoding='utf-8-sig'` will remove the UTF-8-encoded BOM (byte order mark) used as a UTF-8 signature in some files:

```py
import unicodecsv

with open('sample.csv','rb') as f:
    r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    for line in r:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
['003,word one']
['003,word two']
['003,word three']
```

But why are you using the third-party `unicodecsv` with Python 3?  The built-in `csv` module handles Unicode correctly:

```py
import csv

# Note, newline='' is a documented requirement for the csv module
# for reading and writing CSV files.
with open('sample.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        print(line)
```