# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable Error on SELECT Query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

## Introduction

The script I am writing reads from a `.csv` file that has the format of `schema, table, column`, and then executes a `SELECT` query to get the values of all records of those columns. My goal with the script is for it to print out all the values of the columns found in the `.csv` file.

## Problem

When running the script, I receive a `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable` error for the `cursor.execute()` method:

```py
print(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";') # print out query for debugging
cursor.execute(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";')

# Output (Trimmed)
SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM abbotsley_271."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES";
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "abbotsley_271.AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM abbotsley_271."AREA_BUILD_PHASE...
```

As you can see from the output, it is complaining that the relation  `"abbotsley_271.AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"` does not exist, despite that schema and table do exist in the PostgreSQL database.

If I run the printed query from `print()` on a DBMS tool like DBeaver, the query works fine:

[image: Query successful]

Additionally, if I replace the fstrings in the `execute()` method with the printed query, it also works fines:

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM abbotsley_271."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES";')

# Output
PS C:\Users\user> & "C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe" "g:/My Drive/Code Library/Python/Data - character varying to timestamp without time zone.py"
SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM abbotsley_271."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES";
[('2022-07-08 21:53:23',), ('2023-03-13 05:47:28',), ('2022-06-28T16:27:39.000',), ('2023-03-21 20:37:25',), ('2023-02-08 10:00:58',), ('2023-03-22 10:14:39',), ('2023-06-27 16:38:05',), ('2022-06-28T16:30:33.000',), ('2023-03-21 18:53:04',), ('2022-06-28T16:29:20.000',), ('2023-06-27 16:32:05',), ('2023-01-23 06:27:06',), ('2022-07-04T12:17:18.575',), ('2022-06-28T16:29:01.000',), ('2022-06-28T16:55:00.000',), ('2022-07-04 15:31:46',), ('2022-07-06 12:11:00',), ('2022-07-06 17:00:35',), ('2022-07-07 12:13:04',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-07-08 10:55:40',), ('2022-06-28T16:30:42.000',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-06-28T16:27:53.000',), ('2022-06-28T16:28:11.000',), ('2022-06-28T16:28:22.000',), ('2022-06-28T16:28:47.000',), ('2022-06-28T16:29:35.000',), ('2022-07-08 21:53:23',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-06-28T16:30:10.000',), ('2022-06-28T16:30:19.000',), ('2023-02-17 06:59:41',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-06-28T16:33:08.000',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2022-06-28T16:29:55.000',), ('2023-03-21 18:33:08',), ('2022-07-12 00:00:00',), ('2023-03-21 18:47:39',), ('2022-07-08 21:53:23',), ('2023-03-21 18:53:04',)]
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight into this, as I cannot fathom what the issue is.

## Full Script

```py
import psycopg2
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="IP",
    database="db",
    user="user",
    password="password")

cursor = conn.cursor()

with open("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\excel_files\\character varying to timestamp.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_rows = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    columnLengths = []
    
    for value in tqdm(csv_rows, desc="CSV progress"):
        schema = value[0]
        table = value[1]
        column = value[2]
        
        print(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";')
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";') # error location

        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print(data)

        for record in data:
            cvValue = record[0]

            columnLengths.append(f"{schema}, {table}, {column}, {cvValue}")

    for record in columnLengths:
        print(record)
```

## What I Have Tried

- I have tried playing around with the types of encapsulation (`'` vs `"`) to no avail
- Removed `{schema}.` from the query and that avoids the error, but I think this just searches one schema the entire duration of the loop

---

## Update

### Error Message

```bash
SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM "abbotsley_271"."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\My Drive\Code Library\Python\Data - character varying to timestamp without time zone.py", line 30, in <module>
    cursor.execute(tbl_qry.as_string(conn))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "abbotsley_271.AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM "abbotsley_271"."AREA_BUILD_PHA...
```

## Updated Script

```py
import psycopg2
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="host",
    database="db",
    user="user",
    password="password")

cursor = conn.cursor()

with open("C:\\Users\\alex.fletcher\\Downloads\\excel_files\\character varying to timestamp.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_rows = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    columnLengths = []
    
    for value in tqdm(csv_rows, desc="CSV progress"):
        schema = value[0]
        table = value[1]
        column = value[2]

        tbl_qry = sql.SQL("SELECT {} FROM {}").format(
            sql.Identifier(column),
            sql.Identifier(schema, table)
            )

        print(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";')
        # cursor.execute(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";')
        cursor.execute(tbl_qry.as_string(conn))

        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print(data)

        for record in data:
            cvValue = record[0]

            columnLengths.append(f"{schema}, {table}, {column}, {cvValue}")

    for record in columnLengths:
        print(record)
```

Comment: Do not use `f` strings for this. You need to use the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module. The error is that this `"abbotsley_271.AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"` is being seen as a table name not a schema.table_name. That would need to be `"abbotsley_271"."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"`. The `sql` module does the correct quoting and also deals with SQL injection.

Comment: Hmm. Either you are not connecting to the correct database or there is issue with the schema and/or table names. In `psql` what does `\dn` return for the schema names?

Comment: I am definitely connecting to the correct database, and the name of the schema is correct as if I copy the printed query and run the query manually, it works fine as the screenshot shows in the original post.

Comment: 1) What does `\dn` return for the schema names?(Add to question). 2) Does the Postgres log show anything useful when you run the script?

Comment: `\dn` shows the same name as the error does, no difference in naming. Postgres logs don't show anything useful.

Comment: I would bet money the error message is correct. Run the query manually as : `cursor.execute('SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM "abbotsley_271"."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES";')`.

Comment: Running `cursor.execute('SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM "abbotsley_271"."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES";')` worked. If that worked, how come the variables don't work when the structure of the query is identical?

Comment: That is what you are going to have to track down. Start by doing `schema="abbotsley_271"` and `table="AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"` and `column="CREATION_DATE"` then the `tbl_qry = sql.SQL("SELECT {} FROM {}").format(
            sql.Identifier(column),
            sql.Identifier(schema, table)
            )` then `cursor.execute(tbl_qry)`.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the `schema` variable. If I make `schema1 = "abbotsley_271"` and compare `print(schema == schema1)`, it returns false. Both values when printed are `abbotsley_271 abbotsley_271`. Is there some hidden encoding that I am missing?

Comment: I would say that is a good guess. Try `print(repr(schema))`.

Comment: Ah, that prints `'\ufeffabbotsley_271'`. I am not familiar with those characters, what do they mean?

Comment: [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The issue was the encoding that was used to read the `.csv` file was including UTF BOM (byte order mark), which was hidden from print outputs but could be seen with the `repr()` function (thanks to [Adrian Klavian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver)).

By changing the encoding to utf-8-sig ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72466218/ufeff-is-appearing-while-reading-csv-using-unicodecsv-module)), in the `with open(encoding=)`, it removes the BOM and the script runs fine.

## Working Script

```py
import psycopg2
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="host",
    database="db",
    user="user",
    password="password")

cursor = conn.cursor()

with open("C:\\Users\\alex.fletcher\\Downloads\\excel_files\\character varying to timestamp.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    csv_rows = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    columnLengths = []
    
    for value in tqdm(csv_rows, desc="CSV progress"):
        schema = value[0]
        table = value[1]
        column = value[2]

        tbl_qry = sql.SQL("SELECT {} FROM {}").format(
            sql.Identifier(column),
            sql.Identifier(schema, table)
            )

        print(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";')
        # cursor.execute(f'SELECT "{column}" FROM {schema}."{table}";')
        cursor.execute(tbl_qry.as_string(conn))

        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print(data)

        for record in data:
            cvValue = record[0]

            columnLengths.append(f"{schema}, {table}, {column}, {cvValue}")

    for record in columnLengths:
        print(record)
```

Thanks [Adrian Klavian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Example using [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost  user=postgres")
cur = con.cursor()


tbl_qry = sql.SQL("SELECT {} FROM {}").format(sql.Identifier("CREATION_DATE"), 
                  sql.Identifier("abbotsley_271", "AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"))

print(tbl_qry.as_string(con))
SELECT "CREATION_DATE" FROM "abbotsley_271"."AREA_BUILD_PHASE_BOUNDARIES"

cur.execute(tbl_qry)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! Unfortunately, when I try this using the `schema`, `table` and `column` variables, I receive the same error.

I have put my new code into this [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/zxGxH1fp)

Comment: You have not shown the actual values for `schema`, `table`, `column` and what you are printing is the `f` string not `print(tbl_qry.as_string(con))`. Also it should be `con.execute(tbl_qry)`.

Comment: Also provide the actual error message. And add  the revised code as update to your question.

Comment: Hello Adrian, thanks for responding. I have updated the post to include what you asked for. Also, `conn.execute(tbl_qry)` did not work because `'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'execute'`.

Comment: Yeah I have been working with `psycopg(3)` a lot lately and it has `con.execute()`.  Sorry for the mix up. To be complete in the `psycopg` case it would be `cur = con.execute()`. In your case `cur.execute(tbl_qry)`.

Comment: Oh I see, I did not know there was a `psycopg(3)`. Is that something I should look into using instead of `psycopg2`?

Comment: No that is not necessary at this point. There are some significant [differences](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html). It would probably be best to stick with `psycopg2` for the time being, especially as it will be continued to be developed.